# Insert UTF-8 in postgreSQL using hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, utf-8

I am trying to insert UTF-8 in database using hibernate and spring.

```
 <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
    "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
    "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>

<session-factory>



    <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">utf8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>

    <!-- Database connection settings -->
    <property name="connection.driver_class">
        org.postgresql.Driver
    </property>
    <property name="connection.url">
        jdbc:postgresql://192.168.6.51:5432/JayHind?UseUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=utf-8&amp;charSet='UTF8'
    </property>
    <property name="connection.username">postgres</property>
    <property name="connection.password">pshiv</property>

    <!-- JDBC connection pool (use the built-in) -->
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>

    <!-- SQL dialect -->
    <property name="dialect">
        org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
    </property>

    <!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
    <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>

    <!-- Disable the second-level cache  -->
    <property name="cache.provider_class">
        org.hibernate.cache.NoCacheProvider
    </property>

    <!-- Echo all executed SQL to stdout -->
    <property name="show_sql">true</property>

    <!-- Drop and re-create the database schema on startup -->
    <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>



    <mapping class="com.models.Role" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserAttempts" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserLogin" />
    <mapping class="com.models.UserRole" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Program" />
    <mapping class="com.models.NationalProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.StateProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.OtherProgram" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Video" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Contact" />
    <mapping class="com.models.Heading" />
</session-factory>

</hibernate-configuration>
```

My model

```
package com.models;

import static javax.persistence.GenerationType.IDENTITY;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.UniqueConstraint;
import javax.validation.Valid;
import javax.validation.constraints.Pattern;

import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.Email;
import org.hibernate.validator.constraints.NotBlank;
import org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat;

import com.sun.istack.internal.NotNull;

@Entity
@Table(name = "tbl_heading_info", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "id")})
 public class Heading {
 private int id;

@NotNull
@NotBlank
private String message;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(name = "id", unique = true, nullable = false)
public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}

@Column(name = "message", nullable = false)
public String getMessage() {
    return message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    this.message = message;
    /*byte ptext[] = null;
    try {
        ptext = message.getBytes("ISO_8859_1");
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        String value = new String(ptext, "UTF-8");
        this.message=value;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } */

}

}
```

In database following is coming

> àª¸àª°àªàª¾àª°à« àª°à«àª¦àª£àª¾ àª°à«àª¯àª¾...àªàª°à«àª®àªàª¾àª°à«àªàª¨àª¾ àªªàªàª¾àª° àª¹àª®àª£àª¾ àª¨àª¹àª¿ àªµàª§àª¾àª°à«

Spring configuration

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans     
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.2.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

<context:component-scan base-package="com.controller.*" />
<mvc:annotation-driven validator="validator">
    <mvc:argument-resolvers>
        <bean class="com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.spring3.ajax.DatatablesCriteriasMethodArgumentResolver" />
    </mvc:argument-resolvers>

</mvc:annotation-driven>
<mvc:resources mapping="/themes/**" location="/themes/" />
<mvc:resources mapping="/js/**" location="/js/" />


<!-- Apache Tiles -->
<bean id="viewResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass">
        <value>
            org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView
        </value>
    </property>
    <property name="order" value="0" />
</bean>
<bean id="tilesConfigurer"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- Application I18n Message Bundle -->
<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:global" />
    <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
</bean>

<bean id="localeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.CookieLocaleResolver">
    <property name="defaultLocale" value="en" />
    <property name="cookieName" value="DAMLocaleCookie" />
    <property name="cookieMaxAge" value="3600" />
</bean>
<bean id="localeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.LocaleChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="locale" />
</bean>


<!-- Theme Change Interceptor and Resolver definition -->
<bean id="themeSource"
    class="org.springframework.ui.context.support.ResourceBundleThemeSource">
    <property name="basenamePrefix" value="theme-" />
</bean>
<bean id="themeChangeInterceptor"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.ThemeChangeInterceptor">
    <property name="paramName" value="theme" />
</bean>
<bean id="themeResolver"
    class="org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.CookieThemeResolver">
    <property name="defaultThemeName" value="default" />
</bean>
<mvc:interceptors>
    <ref bean="localeChangeInterceptor" />
    <ref bean="themeChangeInterceptor"/>
</mvc:interceptors>

<!-- Localization of hibernate messages during validation!-->
<bean id="validationMessageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename" value="classpath:validation" />
</bean>

<bean name="validator"  class="org.springframework.validation.beanvalidation.LocalValidatorFactoryBean">
    <property name="validationMessageSource">
        <ref bean="validationMessageSource"/>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="multipartResolver"  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
        <!-- one of the properties available; the maximum file size in bytes -->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="9992097152"/>
</bean>

<bean id="UserLoginDAO" class="com.dao.UserLoginDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="ProgramDAO" class="com.dao.ProgramDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="NationalProgramDAO" class="com.dao.NationalProgramDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="StateProgramDAO" class="com.dao.StateProgramDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="OtherProgramDAO" class="com.dao.OtherProgramDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="VideoDAO" class="com.dao.VideoDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="ContactDAO" class="com.dao.ContactDAOImpl"></bean>
<bean id="HeadingDAO" class="com.dao.HeadingDAOImpl"></bean>

</beans>
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

<display-name>Jay hind express</display-name>

<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>

<!-- Spring MVC -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>jayhind-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>jayhind-dispatcher</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>

<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>
        /WEB-INF/spring-database.xml,
        /WEB-INF/spring-security.xml
    </param-value>
</context-param>

<!-- Spring Security -->
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion-Datatables servlet definition -->
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.extras.servlet2.servlet.DatatablesServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>datatablesController</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/datatablesController/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion servlet definition and mapping -->
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>dandelionServlet</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/dandelion-assets/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion filter definition and mapping -->
<filter>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.core.web.DandelionFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>dandelionFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

<!-- Dandelion-Datatables filter used for basic export -->
<filter>
   <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
   <filter-class>com.github.dandelion.datatables.core.web.filter.DatatablesFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>datatables</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping> 
<filter>
<filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter</filter-class>
<init-param>
    <param-name>encoding</param-name>
    <param-value>UTF8</param-value>
</init-param>
<init-param>
    <param-name>forceEncoding</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
<filter-name>SetCharacterEncodingFilter</filter-name>
<url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
</web-app>
```

In  JSP

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<div class="art-layout-wrapper">
<div class="art-content-layout">
    <div class="art-content-layout-row">
        <div class="art-layout-cell art-content">
            <article class="art-post art-article">


                <div class="art-postcontent art-postcontent-0 clearfix">
                    <div class="art-content-layout">
                        <div class="art-content-layout-row">
                            <div class="art-layout-cell layout-item-0" style="width: 100%">
                                <p>
                                    <span style="font-weight: bold;font-color:red;">Breaking News :
                                    <form:form id="programForm" name="programForm" modelAttribute="heading" method='POST' action="updateHeading" > 
                                    <table style="width: 100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                                                <c:if test="${not empty error}">
                                                    <div class="errorMSG">${error}</div>
                                                </c:if>
                                                <c:if test="${not empty msg}">
                                                    <div class="msg">${msg}</div>
                                                </c:if>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <spring:bind path="message">
                                        <tr class="<c:if test="${status.error}"> trError </c:if>" style="width:300px;">
                                            <th class="headerRow thWidth">
                                                <form:label path="message">
                                                    Breaking News :
                                                </form:label>
                                            </th>
                                            <td style="width:40%;">
                                                <form:textarea path="message" id="message" maxlength="200" size="25"/>
                                                <form:hidden path="id"/>
                                            </td>
                                            <td style="width:30%;">
                                                <form:errors path="message"></form:errors>
                                                <label for="message" class="error"></label>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td colspan="3" align="center">
                                                <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Update Breaking News" class="button"/>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        </spring:bind>
                                    </table>
                                    </form:form>
                                    </span>
                                </p>


                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Show your spring configuration.

Comment: I don't think you have to set the charSet='UTF8' in the connection string. Anyhow, have you tried to create the table with your own DDL? There is the 'hbm2ddl=verify' option which checks if the schema is already up to date.

Comment: I edited it for spring configuration and web xml and also for jsp

Comment: schema is already created using hibernate only.

Comment: Can you check which encoding hibernate used for the schema? Also worth is to call 'SHOW client_encoding;'

Comment: it is showing 'UNICODE'

Answer (score 0):

You will not change it from hibernate.
In hibernate you create table, not database, and data base has encoding type.
You have to drop database, and recreate new with encoding utf8.
If you use pgAdminIII, when you create new database:
get in second tab: 'definition', select in droplist 'encoding' value utf8 and template as template0.
After that, hibernate will create tables in utf8.